# Different style being pulled for link attached to image, causing unwanted layers

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I need to update a highly-customized WP website to add a SecureTrust logo and link on the site in a specific location beside other certified seals in the footer.

I attempted to insert the JavaScript into the footer.php but it didn't work/wasn't recognized.  As a work around I edited the style css to show the SecureTrust logo and then added an anchor in the html to place the link.

```
<div class="logo-box"> 
   <span class="example1"></span>
   <span class="iata"></span>
   <span class="securetrust">
      <a href="https://certs.securetrust.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="SecureTrust"><img src="https://companyname/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/tc-seal-blue46.png"></a></span>
</div>
```

```
.securetrust{
    text-indent: -999999px;
    background: url(images/tc-seal-blue46.png) no-repeat scroll left top rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    background-size: contain;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 46px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 8px;
    max-width: 93px;
}
```

The SecureTrust logo is now in place, however the "link" is connecting to a media style and pulling up the site logo, not the .securetrust style in the css.  Images are attached if it helps.

Is there a way to have the link pull the css image?  I have also tried uploading the image separately and direct the a href to pull that but it's not working.

[image: Example - pulling the correct style (.iata style)]

[image: Link with logo overlay - pulling from @media screen showing images/logo.pnh]

Comment: `.logo a` has `text-indent: -999999px` . have you tried that one?

Comment: @Roko I tried modifying the text-indent on the `.logo a` but it's connected to the Generic Styling header.  This solution did fix the securetrust logo problem but then added a link on the logo in the header section on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `logo` class on the parent div is causing the problem, so either get rid of that or if you need to keep it for some reason, try the following.

You need a class that will override the site logo class.
So use `.logo .securetrust` as you css selector rather than just `.securetrust` and put it `securetrust` on the link rather than the span.

HTML

```
<div class="logo col-md-6 col-sm-12"> <!-- <- logo is problem class -->
  <div class="logo-box">
    <span>
      <a href="sealserver.trustwave.com/…" class="securetrust" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="SecureTrust">
        <img src="worldgo.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/…>
      </a>
    </span>
```

CSS

```
// to hide the site logo
.logo .securetrust {
  background: none;
}
// set the size and alignment of the image as required
.logo .securetrust img {
  width: 70px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding the a new .logo.securetrust as and adding securetrust on the link you recommended but it's still trying to pull the header logo on top of the new logo.   Is this the code that you would recommend? 
<span class="logo.securetrust">
    <a href="https://sealserver.trustwave.com/cert.php?customerId=7b8ee88685a74b78b886d5318bd78f5d&amp;size=105x54&amp;style=invert" class=securetrust target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="SecureTrust"><img src="https://worldgo.ca/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/tc-seal-blue46.png"></a></span>